# Check search input if value matches in array and show respons

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

First of all, I am really new to Javascript and has just started the last weeks.

What i want:

A searchbar where a user can type their postcode and then the script searches through array to see if postnumber is in either of the objects - then responding the message found in the object it is located in.

I get it to respond the the message - but only for the first postnumber. I guess the problem is within the loop.

```js
var montering = {
  "postnummer": [{
    "id": "0",
    "codes": ["3089", "2089"],
    "msg": "Message 1"
  }, {
    "id": "1",
    "codes": ["3088", "2088"],
    "msg": "Message 2"
  }]
}



var placeholder = "";
document.getElementById('melding').innerHTML = placeholder;

//Script to search array for a match 
document.getElementById("searchBtn").addEventListener('click', function() {
  var formInput = document.getElementById("formInput").value,
    foundItem = null; //we'll store the matching value here

  if (formInput === '') {
    alert('Tast inn et postnummer');
    return false;
  }

  for (i = 0; i < montering.postnummer.length; i++) {
    if (montering.postnummer[i].codes[i] == formInput) {
      foundItem = montering.postnummer[i].codes[i];
      break; //we've found a match, no sense to continue
    }
  }

  if (foundItem) {
    var msg = document.getElementById('melding');
    melding.innerHTML += 'Melding: ' + montering.postnummer[i].msg;
  } else {
    alert("Code Number: '" + formInput + "' Was Not Found");
  }

});
```

```html
<form method="get" action="input">
  <fieldset>
    <input id="formInput" name="formInput" type="text" placeholder="Tast inn postnummeret ditt" required/>
  </fieldset>
</form>

<input id="searchBtn" type="submit" value="Finn pris">
<p id="melding">Placeholder</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `Array.prototype.includes` on `codes` :

```js
var montering = {
  "postnummer": [{
    "id": "0",
    "codes": ["3089", "2089"],
    "msg": "Message 1"
  }, {
    "id": "1",
    "codes": ["3088", "2088"],
    "msg": "Message 2"
  }]
}



var placeholder = "";
document.getElementById('melding').innerHTML = placeholder;

//Script to search array for a match 
document.getElementById("searchBtn").addEventListener('click', function() {
  var formInput = document.getElementById("formInput").value,
    foundItem = null; //we'll store the matching value here

  if (formInput === '') {
    alert('Tast inn et postnummer');
    return false;
  }

  for (i = 0; i < montering.postnummer.length; i++) {
    if (montering.postnummer[i].codes.includes(formInput)) {   // change this line
      foundItem = montering.postnummer[i].codes[i];
      break; //we've found a match, no sense to continue
    }
  }

  if (foundItem) {
    var msg = document.getElementById('melding');
    melding.innerHTML += 'Melding: ' + montering.postnummer[i].msg;
  } else {
    alert("Code Number: '" + formInput + "' Was Not Found");
  }

});
```

```html
<form method="get" action="input">
  <fieldset>
    <input id="formInput" name="formInput" type="text" placeholder="Tast inn postnummeret ditt" required/>
  </fieldset>
</form>

<input id="searchBtn" type="submit" value="Finn pris">
<p id="melding">Placeholder</p>
```